# Determine the client port in a Flask request

Tags: python, http, flask, tcp, werkzeug

In a Flask server, is it possible to determine the remote *port* of the client?

I see `request.remote_addr` https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Request.remote_addr for the client's IP address, but I'm looking to see if I can determine the client's port.

(I'm using a Flask server as part of a test, testing an HTTP client I'm working on. The client should use re-use connections between requests, so to get evidence of this, am trying to check that the same client port is used across requests. Not a perfect test admittedly, but it is likely good enough for my purposes.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in the `environ` element of the `request` object:

```
request.environ['REMOTE_PORT']
```